# Loop radio-button form javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, forms

I am trying to loop a radio-button form but with no success.

Despite the length of the form is 3 (same as number of radiobuttons) I can not access individual elements.

The purpose is to change the text. Its works If I want to access the first element:

```
var child = form.firstChild;
alert(child.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML);
```

this returns the first radiobutton text.

But if I create a loop out of this

```
function getRadioBInfo() {
    var form = document.getElementById("myform");

    for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
        var iForm = form[i];
        var child = iForm.firstChild;
        alert(child.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

.. I get I TypeError: child is null

What is wrong with this code?

**HTML**

```
<form action="" name="deliver_form" id="myform" style="display: block;">
    <input type="radio" name="delivering" id="radio1" value="deliver"> <label>label1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="delivering" value="comeandtake"> <label>label2</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="delivering" value="express"> <label>label3</label>
</form>
```

Comment: You are looking for the .elements property of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like following.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("myform");
    
for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
    var child = form.getElementsByTagName('input')[i];
    alert(child.nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" name="deliver_form" id="myform" style="display: block;">
    <input type="radio" name="delivering" id="radio1" value="deliver"> <label>label1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="delivering" value="comeandtake"> <label>label2</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="delivering" value="express"> <label>label3</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), you could use:

```
$('[name=delivering']).each( function() {
    alert( $(this).find('label').html() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the label followed after the radio button you could try this:

```
function getRadioBInfo() {

    var form = document.getElementById("myform");
    var radios = form.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        var radio = radios[i];
        console.log(radio.nextSibling.innerHTML);
    }
 }

 getRadioBInfo();
```

**pitfall**: there shouldn't be whitespace between the radio or the button. Otherwise `nextSibling` returns text and not the `label`

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jz5kdrpe/)**

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not getting by `name`

Try this

```
function getRadioBInfo() {

    var arrRadioBtns = document.getElementsByName("delivering");

    for (var i = 0; i < arrRadioBtns.length; i++) {
      var btn = arrRadioBtns[i];          
      alert (btn.value);
    } 
}
```

[**Working Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/nrm24ao0/)

Comment: I think the OP is looking for the text inside the label tag but not the radio button value.Correct me if I ma wrong

Answer (score 0):

form[i] contains only radio buttons.If You want to take the labels Try using

```
var lbl = document.getElementsByTagName('label'); 
for (var i=0;i < lbl.length; i++){ lbl[i].innerHTML = 'radio' + i; }
```

and loop through the labels and change the text

Answer (score 0):

Couple of observation

1. var form = document.getElementById("myform");
     form will not be an array,Instead it will be a String,So you are iteration of the string.length;
2. You can use `doucment.getElementsByName` to get all radio buttons with common name

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
function getRadioBInfo() {
//Retun collection of radio button with same name
var _getRadio = document.getElementsByName("delivering");
// loop through the collection
for(var i = 0;i<_getRadio.length;i++){
//nextElementSibling will return label tag next to each radio input
   console.log(_getRadio[i].nextElementSibling.innerHTML)
  }
}
getRadioBInfo();
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daor385s/)